# TicTacToe Array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

Hey i'm making a TicTacToe game where it checks each index for a value of "x" or "o" and it keeps giving me the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 for the first if statement. Any help as to suggesting why this is happening?

```
public boolean checkRowsForWin(int usrBrd, int WinSeq) {
    int countX = 0;
    int countO = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < usrBrd; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; i< usrBrd; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == 'x') {
                countX++;
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == 'o') {
                countO++;
            }
            else {
                countX = 0;
                countO = 0;
            }
            if (countX >= WinSeq) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (countO >= WinSeq) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's where i initialize the board

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Tic-Tac-Toe!");
    System.out.println("How large would you like the board?(Must be greater 
    than 3)");
    int usrBrd = scnr.nextInt();
    if(usrBrd < 3) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number, please try again");
        usrBrd = scnr.nextInt();
    }
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe(usrBrd);
    game.initializeBoard(usrBrd);
    System.out.println("What should the win sequence be? Write in form of 
    amount i.e \"3\"  ");
    int winSeq = scnr.nextInt();
```

Here's the method for initializing the board

```
public TicTacToe(int usrBrd) {
    board = new char[usrBrd][usrBrd];
    currentPlayerMark = 'x';
    initializeBoard(usrBrd);
}
public void initializeBoard(int usrBrd) {
    //loop rows
    for (int i = 0; i < usrBrd; i++) {
        //loop columns
        for(int j = 0; j < usrBrd; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of usrBrd?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where you initialize your 2d-array `board[i][j]`?

Comment: Where is your initialization of board?

Comment: Also, since java array's are zero based I assume 3 would be out of bounds as you should have 0,1,2 as your values since tic tac toe boards are 3x3 in size.
0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2
1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2
2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2

Comment: usrBrd is the amount of how big they want the board to be

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your second for loop

```
for(int j = 0; i< usrBrd; j++)
```

You always check if i < usrBrd which will always evaluate as true since 'i' will never increment in that for loop.

Comment: fixed it but, now i have an issue where it lets the user win even if they don't have a straight row or column?

Comment: You are only resetting if the value is NOT x or o

if(board[i][j] == 'x') {
                countX++;
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == 'o') {
                countO++;
            }
            else {
                countX = 0;
                countO = 0;
            }

You'll have to dive deeper in your the logic but You need to reset 'x' count if you find an 'o' and vice versa. Otherwise they only reset on empty squares

Comment: thanks, i changed the body of the if statement where if x is detected then countO will reset and vice versa for the else if statement.